# How to disable swaping of images in Magento 1.9.1.0 - swatches

Tags: product, ce-1.9.1.0, product-images, swatches

I've created size swatches for products in Magento 1.9.1.0. Is it possible to disable images swapping for selection of size options. I don't have images for my simple products  so after click on size swatch Magento display blank images. I just want to have images from my configurable products to which my simple products are associated.

Comment: Have a try with my answer at: [How can I stop other attributes changing my swatch image?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93900/33951)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using ce-1.9.1.0 ee-1.14.1. or higher, the feature is already built in, with the so-called Configurable Swatches which allow "Product Image Swap".

You can enable this feature in System > Configuration > CATALOG > Configurable Swatches

[image]

Swap Images Defined by Option Label

One way to configure swap images is to upload images to a configurable product with labels exactly matching the specific option labels (for example, Royal Blue).

Here is an example of a configurable product image gallery images that contains images for three colors:

[image]

Swap Images Defined by Base Image

Another way to configure swap images is to upload base images to each child product of the configurable product.

Here is an example of a Royal Blue child product with an attached base image:
[image]

Source and full documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches