# How to stop changing of base image when size is selected in details page?

Tags: swatches

I have two configurable swatches in details page. Color & size. When I select the size the base image is changing. I want the base image to change only for color swatches and not for size swatches. Please help

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90364/how-can-i-stop-other-attributes-changing-my-swatch-image?rq=1 maybe helpful

Comment: Thank you @QaisarSatti. It worked when I called the js file in page.xml